# Laravel Sanctum Login not working on mobile Safari

Tags: laravel, vue.js, safari, laravel-sanctum

I have a laravel project with VueJs frontend and auth with Laravel sanctum.
Everything works fine, however one user can't login with his iPhone and iPad.

I told him to uncheck "Block all cookies" function and it seems that he didn't have that checked.

What could be the reason for this?

EDIT:
When I test it with multiple iOS devices I can login without any problem.

When I open the login page the following error appears (only in Safari) in the console:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Safari still does not support `'strict-dynamic'` token therefore warns about in the console.
It's not an error, but warning.Browsers always warn about such things, otherwise you have no chances to know what is supported in current browser version.

Just ensure your CSP is in browsers [backward combatibility](https://csplite.com/csp198/#CSP_backward_compatibility) mode (have enough sources to continue working when browsers do not support some tokens). It looks like this is the case as you have checked many different browsers.

That user which can't login with his iPhone and iPad have to check CSP errors in the console, before start tracing whats going on. Alternatively you can use reporting facilities of CSP (`report-uri` directive) to check which violations occur in browsers on the login page.

Comment: thank you for your answer. That problem was not the source of not being able to login. It was much simper - the users had email addresses with double dash -- which was converted to – by the iPhone...

Comment: Really curious. Thank you for clarifying this detail.